# Java manage multiple versions of WSDL clients

Tags: java, wsdl, client

First of all sorry but I don't know how to exactly "name" what I look for, so here is the whole story.

I'm developer a super simple java piece of code (will be a JAR I call by cli) consuming a webservice and doing few things. The webservice gave me a WSDL link, so I successfully create a client with Eclipse providing the WSDL link. The WSDL has multiple versions, depending on the version of the web server app and it changed and evolved over time.
The WSDL client generated by Eclipse has the version in the package name.

How to manage multiple versions of WSDL clients in parallel in my code? I will generate the client for multiple versions of WSDL so that my code could talk with multiple versions of the web service (of course the more recent version is available the better it is, but I need to still be able to consume old versions of the web server too to get at least part of the job done).

What's the name of that thing? (manage multiple versions of WSDL client in java)
What's the ideal way to manage it? Is there a design pattern or something explaining how to use it without having to code everything repeating the code again and again for all the possible versions of WSDL client generated?

I hope it's clear enough (so far in my mind it's still a big confusing as it's like the same thing, a WSDL file, but multiple version = multiple packages ...).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Service Versioning** or **SOA Governance** or **API Governance** or **API Management**? Like that, enterprisy shit))

Take a look to [Architect: Web Services Web Services Versioning by Gabriel Bechara](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/web-services-versioning-094384.html)